# Send argument to batch file containing special characters

Tags: batch-file, arguments, special-characters

How can I send http://httpbin.org/get?course=networking&assignment=1 as an argument to a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

It's a single argument so just place it inside doublequotes!

Possibly like this:

```dos
"MyScript.cmd" "http://httpbin.org/get?course=networking&assignment=1"
```

Or maybe like this:

```dos
Call "MyScript.cmd" "http://httpbin.org/get?course=networking&assignment=1"
```

Comment: Also add, when referencing the argument add a tilde, like `%~1` when you want to strip the quotation marks, or `"%~1"` to quote the value explicitly.  Examples: `set "url=%~1"` to set %url% as the unquoted value, or `wget "%~1"` to quote the value.

Comment: @davidXman, your question is specific to sending an argument, _not receiving one_. For information regarding the receiving the sent argument please refer to the comment above.